# JPA inheritance alternative for SINGLE_TABLE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

AppEngine only supports "TABLE_PER_CLASS" and "MAPPED_SUPERCLASS" for JPA inheritance.
Unfortunately "JOINED" and especially "SINGLE_TABLE" are not supported.

I'm wondering what the best alternative is to implement a SINGLE_TABLE alternative?

My only requirements are:
1) Have separate classes like AbstractEmployee, InternalEmployee, ExternalExmployee.
2) Being able to run a query over all employees, thus resulting in both InternalEmployee and ExternalEmployee instances.

The only thing I'm thinking off is using a 'big' Employee object containing all fields?
Any other ideas?

PS: vote for proper "SINGLE_TABLE" support via http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could in theory use @Embeded and @Embeddable to group related fields into an object. So you would have a class that looks something like.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
     // all the common employee fields go here 
     //

     // the discriminator column on Employee class lets you be specific in your queries          
     private Integer type; 

     @Emebded 
     private Internal internal; // has the fields that are internal

     @Embeded
     private External external; // has the fields that are external 

     equals & hashcode that compare based on the discriminator type and other fields 
}
```

Comment: Yes this might be a good alternative. Let's wait a little bit of time before accepting this as THE answer. Maybe somebody else will also have a valuable addition to this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

What AppEngine supports and doesn't support is misleading there. AppEngine uses a property store, so any Kind can have any properties. Consequently, in principle, a Kind can contain InternalEmployee and ExternalEmployee "instances". The only thing that AppEngine JPA actually does is store all fields of a class in a single Kind object. That doesn't preclude having subtypes stored in the same Kind (with extra properties for the subtype-specific fields), which is the equivalent of "single-table".

PS, raising some issue on "AppEngine" as a whole won't get any response (look at the rest of issues in there ;-) ), bearing in mind the code affected here is in its own project at http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine  and has its own issue tracker

Comment: Haha I know raising issues on "AppEngine" is not really helping :-)

Comment: And yes you are right about what the datastore can handle or not. But when using JPA you are not using the datastore directly and have to play the GAE JPA rules.

Comment: Note that datanuclues-appengine had similar feature request: http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=295